# Android UnsatisfiedLinkError with libicudata after update ndk to r11

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I recently update my ndk version to r11c. I meet some UnsatisfiedLinkError when I try to load my shared library. My project work fine when I use old version of ndk like r9c. And I didn't use the library libicudata.so. I don't know why it says dlopen failed: library "libicudata.so" not found.

I know ndk removed some library, but I'm not sure if it caused my problem.

BTW, I'm using sqlite.so in my project.

Can anyone help me to explain why this happened?

Comment: Can you provide your Android.mk (if you use it), build.gradle, and the code you use to load the library?

Comment: It turns out I added a library named libnativehelper.so which depends on libicudata.so. It seems that ndk generated it automatically. I removed it and everything works fine. I'm not sure about the mechanism of this but I'm keep digging it. Thanks for your help @bullsy

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but I have some idea of what might be going on. I know that libicudata.so was once a system library (under /system/lib on your device) but on my device running 6.0 only libicui18n.so and libicuuc.so are present. Did you update your device OS recently?

Comment: I'm using android 6.0. This problem only happened on 6.0. It may be the reason you said. I recently update the ndk version from r9c to r11c, it's a big step.

Comment: @TerryChao: That was never a supported NDK library, so it won't necessarily always have the same name or even exist. Note that apps using non-NDK libraries will not work in N: http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#ndk

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your kind reminding, I'll optimize my app to run on N.